# package org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign does not exist error

Tags: feign

I tried upgrading "**spring-cloud-netflix-core.version**" from 1.1.7 to 2.2.2 but now i am getting  *"package org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign does not exist"*  error and @ EnableFeignClients this is not recognised. how can i get this resolved.

I tried using this import *"org.springframework.cloud.openfeign" *but didn't work.

Can someone help me resolve this issie